# fatal: fsync error on git/repo/path

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I try to whole day resolve the trouble:
When i try to **pull** or **clone** exists repository in empty directory, i got error:

```
$ git clone https://bitbucket.org/path_to_repo/aroma
Cloning into 'aroma'...
remote: Counting objects: 1335, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1174/1174), done.
remote: Total 1335 (delta 618), rReecused 551 (deltea 72)
Receiving objects: 100% (1335/1335), 43.16 MiB | 3.78 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (618/618), done.
fatal: fsync error on 'H:/Project/testrep/aroma/.git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_xqHCKb': Bad file descriptor
fatal: index-pack failed
```

I tried set pack.windowMemory size and pack.packSizeLimit in config and more. The same error ;[
Before I could to clone repositories. But something went wrong

Comment: The `fsync()` operation ensures that file data are successfully written to stable storage (see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fsync.html or the earlier http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fsync.html). Failure implies that the file system is no longer functioning, i.e., your H: drive is broken.

Comment: So other repos locate *neighbor* and it repos very good pull and push.

Comment: I don't understand that comment, but if you have something that demonstrates that the server itself (the one running the `H:` drive) is fine, then the "broken" part must logically have something to do with the client and/or the client's connection *to* the server.

Comment: Nearby exists repositories have success pull and push commands

Comment: Perhaps, then, you're out of disk space (or disk quota) on the network drive?

Comment: Have you found any solution though?

Answer (score 2):

Check if the issue persists with:

- the [latest version of Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases),
- on a local disk (`C:\` instead of `H:\`)
- from a regular CMD Windows shell session (not `git bash`)

Depending on the nature of the drive `H:\`, you could have issue accessing/updating files because of said nature.

> So other repos locate neighbor and it repos very good pull and push.

If other repos are working from `H:` (meaning you can clone/push/pull from those repos on `H:`), try and duplicate (simple copy) your faulty repo to another folder, and try to clone it from that other folder. If it still fails, something is corrupted in it: time to apply **[`git fsck`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck)** to check it out.

---

Note: with Git 2.42 (Q3 2023), you now can use existing trace2 facility to know more about `fsync` events.

See [commit a27eece](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a27eecea75b3858b4052b191143f144a7e966869) (20 Jul 2023) by [Beat Bolli (`bbolli`)](https://github.com/bbolli).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 52d9dc2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/52d9dc20e1ddd5ac6b9e9113983b2f8d6977e6b0), 02 Aug 2023)</sup>

> ### [`wrapper`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a27eecea75b3858b4052b191143f144a7e966869): use trace2 counters to collect fsync stats
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Beat Bolli</sup>

> As mentioned in the thread starting at [this thread](https://lore.kernel.org/git/20230627195251.1973421-2-calvinwan@google.com/), trace2 counters should be used to count events instead of ad-hoc static variables.
>
> Convert the two fsync static variables to trace2 counters, reducing the coupling between [`wrapper.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a27eecea75b3858b4052b191143f144a7e966869/wrapper.c) and the trace2 subsystem.
> Adjust t/t5351 to match the trace2 counter output format.
>
> The counters are not per-thread because the ones being replaced also were not.

Comment: I tried to use Command windows shell, but I got the same error. I can't use disk C because it SSD. You know, I have 2 PC and it have the same versions git. But one PC have this trouble and the second not. 2.8.1 git version

Comment: @Adobe Can you try with Git 2.11.0.rc3?

Comment: @Adobe And can you try with another drive? (note: all mines are SSD, and git works just fine on them)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same trouble with several Git repositories (from same server). Couldn't pull, couldn't clone.

After restarting my workstation, the problem was gone.

Answer (score -2):

Confirm the config is done for the git, check using the below command.

```
$ git config --list
```

If you can't see anything then setup the config using commands

```
$ git config --global user.name "Your Name"
$ git config --global user.email "youremail@yourdomain.com"
```

confirm again

```
$ git config --list
```

Answer (score -2):

I think the problem is when you are creating ssh key you forget to add it.
ssg-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.
Then copy your key to github and then check if everything is working fine using.
ssh -T git@github.com.
If you get the success. you are all setup.